# Select an option from drop down list excel vba scraping

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, html-select

How can I select an item from drop down option (the drop down is within a table structure)

```html
Sub Test()
    Dim ie          As Object
    
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate ("http://www.handelsregisterbekanntmachungen.de/?aktion=suche#Ergebnis")

        Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .readyState = 4
        
        '.document.getElementsByClassName("vt").Value = "1"
    End With
End Sub
```

When inspecting the element I found name attribute ="vt" ..
Thanks advanced for help

Answer (score 1):

More versatile is to use CSS selectors.

**Collecting all options from target element and indexing for desired option:**

For example, with the day drop down which has name of vt you can use [name=vt] option

The first selector matches all option tag elements within the target parent element that has a `name` attribute with value of `vt`.

[image]

The selector combination is a descendant combinator that includes a leading attribute selector to target the parent drop down for day. As more than one element (all the options) are required the querySelectorAll method is used to return a nodeList which is indexed into to set a particular option to selected:

```
Set list = .querySelectorAll("[name=vt] option") '<==nodeList
list.item(1).Selected = True
```

The last line targets the day 1 option of the drop down.

**Sample of CSS query results:**

[image]

---

**Selecting a single option direct**

Again using the day drop down from `Datum der Bekanntmachung`, you can use a CSS selector of

```
[name=vt] option[value='2']
```

This is another descendant combinator combining two attribute selectors. The parent element has `name` attribute of `vt`, and the target, singular option, child element has `option` tag and attribute `value` with value of `2`. This targets the day 2 option of the drop down.

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub MakeSelections()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://www.handelsregisterbekanntmachungen.de/?aktion=suche#Ergebnis"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim list As Object
        With .document

            Set list = .querySelectorAll("[name=vt] option")
            list.item(1).Selected = True         '<==select first from list
            .querySelector("[name=vt] option[value='2']").Selected = True '<Select second direct
        End With
        Stop '<== Delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve that by looping through the tag name "select"

```html
    For Each e In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("select")
        'Stuff of code
    Next e
```

Thanks a lot